# Matlab figure graph color

Tags: matlab

I have installed Matlab 2013a in my system. When plotting a graph by "ezplot" command, the color of the graphs in the figure is by default set as green. I want to change the color in Deep blue. How is it possible.

Comment: may be this might help? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/165945

Answer (score 0):

After the line with the ezplot command, add this

> set(h, 'Color', 'b');

b is for blue. ither letters will give you red (r), yellow (y) and so forth.